How to properly execute in parallel several fscanf?
I'm trying to do parallel execution of several fscanf to read file faster
I have 10 nums in a file
10-nums.txt
478
205
256
175
196
52
594
333
72
777

and have a simple code
main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("10-nums.txt", "r");
    int x;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        fscanf(file, "%d", &x);
        printf(" %d", x);
    }
}

and here is the output:
7 7 7 205 256 256 256 256 15 7

I have several questions:

From where do 7 and 15 come from? I don't have such a numbers in the list
If I understand correctly I see same numbers (which are actually in my list) because in parallel execution each fscanf doesn't know that where it should be at this moment so several fscanfs can read same line. Is it right assumption?
How to properly execute several fscanfs in parallel?
Does it even make a sense?)

Additional Info:

OS - Windows 10
Compiler - gcc (version 13.1.0) (MinGW)
Build command - gcc.exe "path/to/c/file" -std=c2x -O3 -fopenmp -o some_name

Updated code:
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("nums-10.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File not found\n");
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        int x;
        int y = fscanf(file, "%d", &x);
        printf("thread-num = %d | x = %d | y = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), x, y);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

the output is:
thread-num = 9 | x = 48 | y = 1
thread-num = 4 | x = 6 | y = 1
thread-num = 8 | x = 758 | y = 1
thread-num = 7 | x = 4 | y = 1
thread-num = 6 | x = 167 | y = 1
thread-num = 0 | x = 33 | y = 1
thread-num = 5 | x = 178 | y = 1
thread-num = 1 | x = 32765 | y = 0
thread-num = 3 | x = 6 | y = 1
thread-num = 2 | x = 72 | y = 1

and now none of these numbers are in the my list :)

What OS?  What compiler?  Per C11 7.21.2 Streams, paragraph 7: "Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time."

Note, though, you do not show #include <stdio.h>.

@AndrewHenle Thanks! Is it true for older versions of C2X? If 1 thread at the time can lock file then why I get numbers which are not in my list?

I may be wrong, as I am not that familiar with OpenMP, but if I am not mistaken, then all threads are sharing the same variable x. This is not what you want. I believe that defining the variable x inside the loop will fix this problem, as every thread will then get its own copy.

You may also have a race condition on x.  Offhand, I don't recall enough about OMP to be sure.

@AndrewHenle Will the problem (non-existent numbers) go away if I switch to thread.h? May be you are familiar with it :)

@AndrewHenle When I move the x inside for the output become more unclear 27805 4 26 5 175 32765 0 32765 196 52 :)

"Does it even make a sense" Not really. IO streaming is generally inherently sequential. So this cannot be done directly in parallel. However, you can just split the lines in sequential and then convert the lines to integers in parallel. String parsing is what is slow so doing this in two parts is fine. You can overlap this better with tasks but this is a but more complex for OpenMP beginners.

By the way, don't forget to fclose the file. Please also note that scanf/fscanf tends to be slow (because it needs to parse both the input format and the input string). Consider using specialized parsing functions for that (possibly one fitting specifically your needs for better performance).

One possible explanation for the strange numbers is that fopen returned NULL for some reason and that fscanf is therefore failing, too. You should verify that fopen was successful.

@JérômeRichard Thank you! I hope I will try this way) Oh, yes, forgot to close...

@AndreasWenzel How it can be NULL if I have this file and it works when I remove #pragma directive?

It can be NULL and you must check it. It's no use saying "but it worked".

@EzioMercer: If the program works in single-threaded mode, then you are correct that fopen is probably not returning NULL. However, it probably still is a good idea to check it, because there are many possible reasons for fopen to fail. Although, it would probably also be a good idea to check the return value of fscanf.

@AndreasWenzel I added this before #pragma directive if (file == NULL) {printf("File not found\n");} and the message didn't shown

@AndreasWenzel fscanf sometime 0 and sometime 1. Each time different times 0 and 1

@EzioMercer: That should not be happening. My guess is that you are using a C runtime library that does not perform proper locking, as required by the ISO C standard. In your question, you state that you are using GCC on Windows. Are you using MinGW-w64 or Cygwin, or something else? And which version are you using?

@AndreasWenzel It is MinGW. gcc is version 13.1.0. Added to the question

It is already clear from the comments why your original posted code does not work. However, since you have made many changes to your original posted code in the mean time, it may be helpful if you also showed us the latest version of your code, so that we can examine it for mistakes. It may be best if you add it to the bottom of your question, and also post the exact output of your new code.

@AndreasWenzel Added updated version

In your "updated code", you are still using the shared variable x by all threads, instead of declaring it inside the loop, so that every thread gets its own copy. This explains why the numbers are still wrong. However, it does not explain why fscanf sometimes returns 0. Can you please fix the x variable in the updated code and then post the exact output that you are getting from the updated code?

@AndreasWenzel I already tried it and it didn't help so I return back the variable. Give me 1 min I will give updated output when x is inside for loop

Does your "updated code" still work when you disable the OpenMP #pragma, i.e. when you switch to single-threaded code?

@AndreasWenzel Yes, it works

The large numbers you are getting are the result of fscanf failing, as y is 0, indicating zero matched input items. What you are seeing are some random values as x is uninitialized.

BTW, If you are meaning to run it with optimizations,  -O3 is the correct switch. -o3 will just name the executable 3.

Since the current issue with the "updated code" is significantly different from the issue with your original code (where your code itself was buggy), it may be meaningful to post a new question regarding your "updated code". However, if you post a new question, I suggest that you combine both printf statements into a single printf statement, because otherwise, it is possible that another thread will print something between the first printf statement and the second one, and you won't know which thread printed what.

FWIW I wrote this https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Integer-Duplicate-Count/blob/main/hashmap4.c was much faster than when using fsanf(). It reads into a buffer, then converts to ints without using any of the scanf functions, which I seem to think were about 4x slower.

When fopen returns NULL, I suggest that you exit the program immediately (e.g. using exit(EXIT_FAILURE);), instead of continuing execution and invoking undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can cause all kinds of different errors.

Even after fixing the race and reading serially, then parsing, you may still not improve performance. See https://cpufun.substack.com/p/processing-a-file-with-openmp

I tested your "updated code" on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on Windows and it works as intended. Therefore, I suspect that the issue is with Mingw-w64, or rather the runtime library that Mingw is using. If I had to guess, I would say that your version of Mingw is using the single-threaded version of MSVCRT (which is not thread-safe), instead of the multi-threaded version.

@AndreasWenzel Wow... I tried on my machine and it works too but without any parallelism just like regular loop. It just ignored all flags which I passes for gcc. How did you combine clang and openmp? I tried to add -Xclang but it ignores it too :)

@EzioMercer: On Linux, you can use clang and gcc with the -fopenmp command-line option. I don't know whether this also works on Microsoft Windows.

I suggest that you change your two printf statements to the following: printf("%d %d %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), y, x ); -- That way, you can see how many threads there are and which thread is printing what. You will probably have to #include <omp.h>.

@AndreasWenzel Any way thank you very much for you time and clearing a lot of things for me!

@AndreasWenzel Interesting coincidence - all my y are 1 but nothing has changed :) (I updated that but you can see output in history of my question). I added thread nums too

@EzioMercer: One of your y's is 0. As previously stated, I suspect that all of this misbehavior is due to Mingw using a non-thread-safe version of the old "msvcrt" runtime library. However, according to this page, MSYS2 also supports an environment that uses the "ucrt" library instead, which is a modern version of the runtime library. I guess that this version is always thread-safe. You may want to try compiling in that environment.

@AndreasWenzel You misunderstood me :) Look at the history of changes of my question. In previous one all of them (y) was 1

@AndreasWenzel OMG. I'm so sorry. I forgot that SO rewrite changes in 5 min so it not in the history list... Forget about it I lost my evidences....... I hope your advice will help me :)

@EzioMercer: It does not matter much whether y is 0 or 1. The fact that y is sometimes 0 is just further evidence of something going completely wrong. In my previous message, I stated a possible reason for this and also possibly how to fix it.

@AndreasWenzel Of course! You are absolutely right! I read your messages. You helped me more than a lot
